# R irregular repeating sequence

Tags: r, sequence

I need to create a sequence like this: 112223344455666... where the odd numbers are repeated twice and the evens are repeated three times. Do I have to use a WHILE loop, or is there an easy R way to do this?

Comment: maybe `rep(1:6,(1:6+1)%%2+2)`?

Comment: How about `rep(1:6,3-1:6%%2)`. (Saves a few characters, and an operation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeat can do it. It can be made into a function that generalizes whichever part varies for you.

```
rep(1:6,rep(2:3,3))
[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6
```